# c# DataGridView leave event makes Windows form unresponsive

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I've come across something odd in my c#-4.0 Windows Form application and I'm not sure what's causing it. Basically, I have a form with a DataGridView and some text boxes, in my grid I have a leave event that selects `Rows[0].Cells[0]` when the user leaves the DataGridView.

Now, if I click on a cell within my grid, edit the cell and click straight into a textbox the leave event fires correctly and selects row/cell[0], but at this point the form becomes unresponsive.

How to Replicate with Visual Studio (I'm using 2010 Pro)

- Create new *WindowsFormApplication*
- Add a *DataGridView* and *TextBox* to the form.
- Now, in Form1_Load event add the following code:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DataTable dtTmp = new DataTable("temp");
      dtTmp.Columns.Add("col 1", typeof(String));
      dtTmp.Columns.Add("col 2", typeof(String));

      DataSet dsTmp = new DataSet();
      dsTmp.Tables.Add(dtTmp);

      DataRow dr1 = dsTmp.Tables["temp"].NewRow();
      dr1["col 1"] = "aaa";
      dr1["col 2"] = "12";
      dsTmp.Tables["temp"].Rows.Add(dr1);

      DataRow dr2 = dsTmp.Tables["temp"].NewRow();
      dr2["col 1"] = "bbb";
      dr2["col 2"] = "1234";
      dsTmp.Tables["temp"].Rows.Add(dr2);

      dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTmp;
      dataGridView1.DataMember = "temp";
      dataGridView1.Refresh();
  }
  ```

Next, create a Leave event for DataGridView1 and add the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Debug and perform the following steps:

1. Click the cell in the second row in *col 1* that contains *"bbb"*.
2. Type something else into that cell.
3. ***Without hitting enter, space, tab, down or right arrow***, click into the *textbox* you added to the form.

Now try to close the form, it doesn't close.

What is wrong with my `dataGridView1.CurrentCell` line? If you select and edit the first row, the form closes fine, but not if it's the second.

Comment: @Shaharyar The code the OP posted reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how it is interfering, but that Leave event is interfering with something.  As is usually my cure, try running the code *after* the Leave event:

```
void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0) {
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
    }
  }));
}
```